# auto layout horizontal and vertical format together

Tags: iphone, ios, constraints, autolayout

How to add horizontal and vertical visual format together in the constraintsWithVisualFormat ? There is just horizontal. I want to add V:|-50-[leftButton] and V:|-50-[rightButton] to it. How to do that? Create another NSLayoutConstraint?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [leftButton setTitle:@"Left" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:leftButton];
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [rightButton setTitle:@"Right" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:rightButton];

    NSArray *layoutConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[leftButton(>=80)]-50-[rightButton(>=80)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(leftButton, rightButton)];
    [self.view addConstraints:layoutConstraints];
}
```

Comment: put it with image and then explain what you want.. its for more better understanding :)

Comment: @iPatel I just answered myself. Tell me if it's the way of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create as many separate sets of constraints using visual format as you like. You can't mix horizontal and vertical constraints in the same string, but there is nothing stopping you from creating:

```
H:|-[view]-|
```

Followed by

```
V:|-[view]-|
```

Think of each VFL statement as expressing layout in a single row or column of the superview.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I figured out. I should create another constraint like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonLayoutConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];
    [self.view addConstraint:leftButtonLayoutConstraint];
```

Tell me if this is the best way to do this. But it works any way.

Answer (score 1):

I did a category for NSLayoutConstraint that accepts a string with both horizontal and vertical VFL declarations because i noticed most of time I needed both (H: ,V:) on the same objects

```
@implementation NSLayoutConstraint (CombinedVFL)

+(NSArray *)constraintsWithCombinedVisualFormat:(NSString *)combinedFormat views:(NSDictionary *)views
{
     int indexOfVerticalChar = [combinedFormat rangeOfString:@"V:"].location;
     NSString *verticalString = [combinedFormat substringFromIndex: indexOfVerticalChar];
     NSString *horizontalString = [combinedFormat substringToIndex: indexOfVerticalChar - 1 ]; // trim

     return [[self constraintsForString:horizontalString views:views] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[self constraintsForString:verticalString views:views]];
}

+(NSArray *)constraintsForString:(NSString *)string views:(NSDictionary *)views
{
     return [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:string options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
}

@end
```

To call:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithCombinedVisualFormat:@"H:|[topBorder]| V:|[topBorder(1)]" views:@{ @"topBorder" : topBorder}]];
```

I put the code on my github: https://github.com/dannyshmueli/NSLayoutConstraint-CombinedVFL